# colSums for specific value names

Tags: r

How can I use *colSums* for a specific value names?
Let's say I have a data frame with a `Name` column which includes this names: green, red, pink.

I want to use *colSums* only for the rows named 'pink'- this is what I tried to do:

```
colSums(Filter(is.numeric, df$Name=="pink"))
```

I got this error:

> 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Answer (score 2):

Subset numeric columns and subset rows where Name is pink, then columns sums:

```
colSums(df[ df$Name == "pink", sapply(df, is.numeric) ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Subset the row and use `colSums` -

```
colSums(subset(df, Name=="pink"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Second argument to `Filter()` (`x`) is a `data.frame` not a logical vector.

```
colSums(Filter(is.numeric, df[df$Name=="pink", ]))
```